# Commandline - Change path and run "npm install" on the same line

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, gulp

Is it possible to write a Command line that changes path before `npm install`

e.g. command line:

```
- cd /d "d:\development\test" npm install
```

We want to execute `npm install`from our build server, hence we first need to change the path so Node will install `node_modules` in the right directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /d "d:\development\test" && npm install
```

The `&&` operator will execute the right cmd part only if the left one succeed. If you want to execute `npm install` even if the left part failed, use

```
cd /d "d:\development\test"; npm install
```

Comment: No problem. Do not forget to validate the answer if is okay for you ;)

Comment: I always do, but I have to wait 7 more mins

Comment: Ahah no problem ! I'm so quick :p